# GIMP 2.10.24 : Modify or remove selection's border after closing *.xcf file

Tags: gimp

With GIMP, I want to draw a rectangle so I follow the documentation: [14.2. Creating a Basic Shape](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-using-rectangular.html). I get the expected result.

Then I close the *.xcf file and re-open it. The selection is still active (as you can see in the screenshot below).

Problem: I can't modify or remove the border.

Any suggestion to solve this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Any chance you could share the XCF file?

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/view/fd8r25o3f2spsvq/selection_border.xcf/file (the link is likely to be valid only for the next 14 days, starting on 2021 August 20th)

Comment: Thanks. After opening I see nothing wrong here at all. GIMP is just showing the last selection you made. To fix it do Select > None, and resave. As for the thick yellow stroke, nothing you can really do to remove that since it's not on its own layer.  If you want to be able to change things later, make sure you put edits on layers so you can easily edit or remove them later.

Comment: My problem is that I can remove the yellow stroke (even if the selection is still the same as before closing the file)

Comment: You can't remove the yellow stroke because it's all on the same layer - it's part of the image. So it can't be done. Sorry.  You'd need a layered file - but that's not what you've got. Go learn about GIMP layers and how they work. Find beginner tutorials on youtube. This is really basic stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection is part of the image, so it is saved with the XCF (there are many cases where it is useful...). If you don't want it, do `Select > None` before saving (or after reloading).

The border is easy to remove if you draw it on its own, initially transparent,  layer (which in your case could be just adding the layer before doing `Edit > Stroke selection`) Then as long as you keep the layers distinct (in other words if you don't "flatten" the image, but you normally don't need to do this, it is flattened implicitly when you export to JPG/PNG), you can remove the border by removing the layer on which it was painted (or just making that layer invisible).

In other words, to obtain this:

[image]

You do this:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I came to this conclusion... So I have reworked my original image again, but this time I have added a second layer to draw my selection. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Additional question: how doyou create such a view of your layers? :o

Comment: See [`ofn-perspective-stack`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/)

Comment: Thanks! I will try it!